# How to remove screen names from a tab bar

Tags: react-native, navigation, expo

I use this tab bar to navigate in my app and I don't know how to remove the names under the icons, any tips?

[image]

Comment: You haven't included any information about how you've implemented that tab bar (library, version, code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In  your `TabBar` configurations set the `title=""`. This will not show the label.

Check out working example [here](https://snack.expo.io/@kartikeyvaish/without-labels-tab)

```
<Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
      title: '', // This is the main part...
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => GiveIcon({ route, focused, color, size }) })}
      tabBarOptions={{
      activeTintColor: 'tomato',
      inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
    }}>
    <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
    <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
  </Tab.Navigator>
```